# c# Exception handling based on Java-Webservice

Tags: java, c#, web-services

we are using a java-webservice for importing certain types of data into our system. So they give us a .wsdl and Visual Studio generated the c#-code out of it.

Everything worked fine so far, but how do I handle exceptions that are defined by the webservice?

The exception-class looks like this:

```
public partial class ServiceException : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string causeMessageField;

        private int errorCodeField;

        private MessageEvent[] listField;

        private string messageField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
        public string causeMessage {
            get {
                return this.causeMessageField;
            }
            set {
                this.causeMessageField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("causeMessage");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
        public int errorCode {
            get {
                return this.errorCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.errorCodeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("errorCode");
            }
        }
```

As you can see the class ServiceException is not even derived from System.Exception. So how can I catch it?
I originally planned to catch it like this, but of course that only works with a proper Exception:

```
 catch (ServiceException e)
 {
   throw;
 }
```

Response:

```
91
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body><env:Fault><env:Code><env:Value>env:Receiver
c
</env:Value>
b
</env:Code>
39
<env:Reason><env:Text xml:lang='de-DE'>Fachlicher Fehler:
b
</env:Text>
d
</env:Reason>
6f
<env:Detail><ns2:ServiceFault xmlns:ns2='xxxxxx'><errorCode>0
c
</errorCode>
3b
<list><MessageEvent><MessageInstanceId>-9223372036854775078
14
</MessageInstanceId>
14
<MessageCode>CRM9005
e
</MessageCode>
2f
<ShortMessage>Aufgabendefinition nicht gefunden
f
</ShortMessage>
43
<DetailMessage>Die Aufgabendefinition (#test) wurde nicht gefunden.
10
</DetailMessage>
13
<SeverityType>Error
f
</SeverityType>
f
</MessageEvent>
7
</list>
1b
<message>Fachlicher Fehler:
a
</message>
13
</ns2:ServiceFault>
d
</env:Detail>
c
</env:Fault>
1a
</env:Body></env:Envelope>
0
```

I basically need the DetailMessage, but I have no clue how.

[UPDATE] Oh dear god .. and here I thought this would be more difficult. Just have to use a FaultException to handle this and get whatever I want out of it. Thanks @Agalo. Please make your reply an answer.

Comment: If it's not derived from `System.Exception` then it's impossible for it to be thrown (that is, you don't need to catch it).

Comment: Can you show a sample of response? this exception will not fire because it's `soap` response and it' will come as response item member

Comment: In Service Oriented Architecture, Standard way of Exception handling is by using Faults. So, Java Service would throw Fault and you need to handle the faults.

Comment: Voting -1 for no reason with no explanation; awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    catch (FaultException<ServiceException> e)
    {
        aufgabe.Error = Exceptionhandler.GetFaultExceptionMessages(e);
        aufgabe.IsProcessed = true;
        db.Edit(aufgabe);
        db.Dispose();
    }




public static string GetFaultExceptionMessages(FaultException<ServiceException> e)
        {
            var msgs = "";
            foreach (var error in e.Detail.list)
            {
                msgs += error.DetailMessage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            return msgs;
        }
```